# "Mom was saying that dad wanted me to mow the lawn and asked what time I would be coming home?"

Tags: ambiguity, subjects, indirect-speech

> Mom was saying that dad wanted me to mow the lawn and asked what time I would be coming home.

In the sentence above, who is asking what time I would be coming home, mom or dad? If it's mom, why isn't it dad? And if it is the dad, why isn't it mom?

Basically which subject is the *and* for? Mom or Dad? What are the rules?

Comment: I’m not sure why you would think there are rules to resolve [attachment ambiguities](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22attachment+ambiguity%22).

Comment: I'd expect 'had asked' if the question was dad's. A 'she' or 'that he had' disambiguates perfectly.

Comment: I think it's ambiguous. I also gravitate towards mom asking, but it could be either.

Comment: The "lawn and asked" is part of the same clauae--dad had two messages to relay to mom: mow the lawn, and what time will you be home. The subject "Dad" is being applied to both verba, asked and wanted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you would not use "had asked" because "had wanted" was not used. There is no reason change tense.

Comment: @Lisa P. 'Wanted' is ongoing within the framework ('was wanting' is not really available as it is unidiomatic) whereas dad's asking is a punctive event; 'had asked' is at least as acceptable grammatically as 'asked' here, and better pragmatically as it clearly disambiguates. / You won't be taken seriously with 'clauae', 'verba' and 'there is no reason change tense' within 5 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is ambiguous but I think it was the dad who asked the time. Let's break down the sentence and convert it to Active voice.

> Mom was saying that dad wanted me to mow the lawn and asked what time I would be coming home.

will break down to

> Mom was saying that | dad wanted me to mow the lawn | and | asked what time I would be coming home.
>
> The mom probably said "Dad wants you to mow the lawn and asked what time he will be home.?".
>
> The dad probably told mother,"I want him to mow the lawn and at what
> time will he be home.?".

Comment: My reading goes *Mom was saying / that dad wanted me to mow the lawn / and (she) asked what time I would be coming home*.  Possibly for reasons in the second comment above.

Comment: I'm largely with Dan but could you accept that it's simply a badly written sentence and any attempt to give it a clear meaning is bound to fail?